# What should be the Vout for a CM-driven amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I am somewhat confused by what should be the amplifier output voltage after a purely CM signal is fed. Let me it clarify what I'm talking about:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFpVA6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I would say it should be \$0\$ because, assuming large DC CMRR, such 1V CM will be blasted off by the amplifier. Mathematically, since \$v_{out} = A_{diff}(v_{diff}+\frac{v_{CM}}{CMRR})\$.

**However**, I'm rather told one should expect a **midrange** output wrt supply rails, from a *design* standpoint. Thus, if say the amplifier is railed from +3V to 0V then I should expect \$V_{out}=1.5V\$. This criteria actually leads to some design specs at the output stage, where one should size the transistors to have exactly the same current.

This standpoint eventually results in the same conclusion if supply rails are symmetric e.g. from +3V to -3V, but then I wouldn't expect a Vout = 0V for +3V and 0V, as Circuitlab says.

So, which one is correct? Or are we talking about the same thing?

---

**Clarifications are due, I'm sorry.** I do know a **real** amplifier will inevitabily be affected by a statistical offset voltage, likely leading to saturation close to rails depending on polarity. But that's not the point of the question.

My question is: if theoretically \$\mathbf {V_{OS}=0}\$, then, for high CMRR, should one expect Vout to be slightly above 0V (i.e. regardless of the opamp supply rails) or should one expect it to be at mid range i.e. close to \$(Vcc-|Vss|)/2\$? From the previous \$v_{out}\$ equation, I would say the former -- but I wouldn't know whether the output stage *may* be able to reach it without a negative rail (if for instance the opamp was powered with +3V and ground on the lower side).

Comment: (1V / CMRR + input offset voltage) * open loop gain. Bounded by teh supply rails.

Comment: Theoretically: yes \$V_{out}\$ = 0, in the real world: see Brian's comment. Realize that in a simulator you could be simulating the theoretical situation. The next level of using a circuit simulator is knowing when you can trust its results and when you cannot (and this is one of those cases). So **stop thinking that the simulator is always correct**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Surely, but I wasn't saying that. If you take into account non-idealities such as finite Vos, bias currents etc. then definitely Vout will be above the ideal value by some mV (say). But my question is what **should Vout be**? Midrange wrt supplies or 0? Hope the question is clear, please say if not.

Comment: This is impossible to predict. You need to instead measure the gain error using a differential input with feedback, taking into account the effect of limited op-amp gain.

Comment: *But my question is what should Vout be?* See the first comment. Also realize that the input offset voltage **varies per device**. input offset voltage **does not have one value**. Maybe you're expecting one value like: Vout = 1 V. That's not what is happening here. Vout **depends on chance**, for many opamps Vout = voltage of positive supply - some value and for many most others it will be: Vout = voltage of negative supply + some value.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: I've edited the question, sorry. My doubt is about computing the Vout _without_ offset taken into account i.e. with the equation I mentioned where I silently neglected it. Such eq. says it'd be close to 0, and I'd expect it, but from a design pov I'm _instead_ told I should rather expect a Vout to be at the average of the supplies (so if it's just 3V, Vout = 1.5V). That's what confuses me.

Comment: You should **choose** what answer you want, do you want the theoretical Vout = 0 V that will **never happen** in the real world or do you want the **real world answer** which is that Vout will be close to 0 V or close to 3 V, depending on the offset of the opamp you're using at that moment. You seem to be wanting both at the same time or one universally true answer but that's not going to happen. Also realize that using an opamp like shown in the schematic is **not useful a real world application** of an opamp.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Well, you're saying theoretically it will be Vout=0V. Thus, you're saying it will **not** be at midrange (so Vout=1.5V) and hence dependent on supplies used, which is what I'm (assumingly) wrongly told; if you give circuital evidence for your reasoning, I'll be happy to read it through.

Comment: Why don't you fill in the formula and see how Vout = 0 V? Why would Vout = 1.5 V. **The formula doesn't account for the supply voltages**. If you power the opamp with a symmetrical supply like +3 V and - 3V then Vout = 0 V **is midrange**. You could make a more complicated theoretical model of the opamp which takes the supply voltages into account which then gives Vout = 1.5 for a +3V single supply, simply add (Vcc + Vee) /2 (note how Vee is 0 V or a negative voltage) to the formula in the first comment above.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Because that formula is not the full story, as you say. Consider, for simplicity, a PMOS-NMOS output branch: if sized correctly, they'll have the same current flowing in the branch, hence same Vds. If you take the Vout at the drain terminal (buffered or unbuffered is irrelevant), then the NMOS Vds=Vout will be exactly at Vdd/2 if Vss=0. You wouldn't get Vout=0V. That's what puzzles me.

Comment: Expecting an "exactly sized PMOS + NMOS output" to settle "in the middle": have you ever tried that? Yes in theory that works but in practice it never does because the output leakage currents are unpredictable and very temperature sensitive. So with an opamp based on real (or even modelled in a simulator) transistors, you will **NEVER** see the output settle on Vdd/2. That can only happen in the simulator, using a model based on a formula. That is a very theoretical situation that never happens in the real world.

Comment: So what you describe *You wouldn't get Vout=0V* is **incorrect**. You will get Vout = 0 or Vout = Vcc. The Vout = Vcc/2 can only happen **in theory** or an **ideal model**, a model that involves no transistors at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an open loop amplifier, with colossal gain, and finite but unknown input offsets, you should regard the output voltage as completely undefined.

If you take any real amplifier from your spares box and wire it up like that, it's more likely for the output to be saturated on one or other rail as it is to be in the linear region between them. That's what should be expected from a design standpoint.

With a simulated opamp, it depends what the model for the amplifier does. If it is is given precisely 0 V for the input offsets, and a very large CMRR, then you may get a mid rail output.